# Adding class "active" on Boostrap 4 carousel via jquery, doesnt work correctly when loading data from mongodb

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, mongodb, ejs

I have a carousel and i want to load the pictures on the carousel from my mongodb database. Thus, i need to set the active class on the first item only. What i have tried so far doesnt work. It adds the active class, but then the carousel stays on the first item only.

Below is the code:

**EJS:**

```
    <!-- language: HTML -->
<div id="homePageCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">

<% contests.forEach(function(contest){ %>
  <!--Indicators-->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#homePageCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#homePageCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#homePageCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <!--/.Indicators-->
  <!--Slides-->
  <div class="carousel-inner mb-3" role="listbox">
    <div class="carousel-item">

      <div class="view">
        <img class="d-block carouselImage" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(68).jpg" alt="First slide">
        <div class="mask rgba-black-light"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3 class="h3-responsive"><%= contest.title %></h3>
        <a href="/categories/<%= contest.categoryName %>/<%= contest._id %>" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm card-button mt-3">Μάθε Περισσότερα</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--/.Slides-->
  <!--Controls-->
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#homePageCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#homePageCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
  <!--/.Controls-->
<% }); %>
</div>
```

**jQquery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#homePageCarousel').find('.carousel-item').first().addClass('active');
});
```

So this, will show only the first item and not the rest. What im i doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#homePageCarousel').find('.carousel-item').first().addClass('active');
 var item=$('#homePageCarousel').find('.carousel-item').first().attr("class");
 alert(item);
});
```

```css
.active{
    background: red;
    color:#fff
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="homePageCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
  <!--Indicators-->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#homePageCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#homePageCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#homePageCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <!--/.Indicators-->
  <!--Slides-->
  <div class="carousel-inner mb-3" role="listbox">
    <div class="carousel-item" id="first">

      <div class="view">
        <img class="d-block carouselImage" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(68).jpg" alt="First slide">
        <div class="mask rgba-black-light"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3 class="h3-responsive"></h3>
        <a href="/categories/<%= contest.categoryName %>/<%= contest._id %>" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm card-button mt-3">Μάθε Περισσότερα</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--/.Slides-->
  <!--Controls-->
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#homePageCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#homePageCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
  <!--/.Controls-->
</div>
```

Comment: not sure how this is any different of what i tried.

Comment: you might missed referring `jquery ` or misplaced it...Put `jquery `  on the top of all others scripts

Comment: I have tried with your code...see the results now.Its working fine.So i think you have to put the Jquery script reference at the top of all the scripts